# Sort list of alphanumeric strings

Tags: python, string, sorting, alphanumeric

I have a list of strings, each of which will something like ';2234661;E3006345_2234661_FRONT_Image_Container;\n' that I need to sort. Each string will start with a semi-colon and different numbers, but I need them all to be sorted according to the image angle (ex. FRONT, BACK, LEFT) in a non-alphabetical order following this ranking:
FRONT
BACK
LEFT
RIGHT
INGREDIENTS
INSTRUCTIONS
INFO
NUTRITION
PRODUCT

Example Input:

```
[';2234661;PRODUCT;', ';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;']
```

Desired Output

```
[';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;PRODUCT;']
```

Here is my code, based off of the solution to a similar issue I found here on stackexchange. However, it returns the error "ValueError: substring not found

```
galleryImages = [';2234661;PRODUCT;', ';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;']

alphabet = 'FBLRINP'

newGallery = sorted(galleryImages, key=lambda word: [alphabet.index(c) for c in word])

print(newGallery)
```

Comment: You are almost there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
>>> my_list = [';2234661;PRODUCT;', ';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;']

>>> my_sorting_logic  = ['FRONT', 'BACK', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'INGREDIENTS', 'INSTRUCTIONS', 'INFO', 'NUTRITION', 'PRODUCT']
```

**Sort on the basis of key's index**

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key = lambda x : my_sorting_logic.index(x.split(';')[2]))
```

Output :

```
[';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;PRODUCT;']
```

Comment: This is helpful, I will give it a try! I may have to do multiple splits. I simplified my input strings a little to distill the question. They actually look a bit more like this:
';2234661;E3006345_2234661_PRODUCT_Image_Container;\n'

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [';2234661;PRODUCT;', ';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;']
keys = ['FRONT', 'BACK', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'INGREDIENTS', 'INSTRUCTIONS', 'INFO', 'NUTRITION', 'PRODUCT']

res = [key for x in keys for key in data if key.split(';')[2] == x]
```

**Output:**

```
[';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;PRODUCT;']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [';2234661;PRODUCT;', ';2234661;FRONT;', ';2234661;LEFT;', ';2234661;RIGHT;', ';2234661;BACK;', ';2234661;INGREDIENTS;', ';2234661;NUTRITION;', ';2234661;INSTRUCTIONS;', ';2234661;INFO;']

# create a dictionary of the form {"FRONT": 0, "BACK": 1, …}
angle = { e: i for i, e in enumerate(['FRONT', 'BACK', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'INGREDIENTS', 'INSTRUCTIONS', 'INFO', 'NUTRITION', 'PRODUCT']) }

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: angle[x.split(';')[2]], reverse=True)

print(my_list)
```